# How to report a visual studio bug?

Tags: visual-studio

Here is a little funny story about Microsoft Products:

Visual Studio notified my that an update for Visual Studio would be  available.

[image]

If I follow the suggestion and click the update button, the Visual Studio installer is started and ... guess what... tells me that no update is available ?!

I searched how to report that issue and the suggestion was to use the
"Report problem" feature of the installer:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio-2017?view=vs-2017

Guess what? The login for that feature does not work ?!:

[image]

If I follow that link one could expect an easy way to leave a message.

Guess what? Only for company users with a subscription?!

=>Microsoft seems to use all kind of strategies one can think of to **avoid user feedback**. Well done.

**=>Do you know a way to hack that barriers and actually let them know that the Visual Studio update does not work as expected? :)**

(The work around is to manually start the installer. Then a message will pop up, saying that the installer needs to be updated...finally Visual Studio itself can be updated.)

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what your exact problem would be but that link works fine for me. However it simply sends you to documentation about how to report issues.

I've reported a couple of bugs in the recent past using the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/) forum and have gotten good results.

Comment: How exactly do you report a bug there? If I click "Report a problem" on the Developer Community page ... I get a pop up telling me to do it from within Visual studio... which does not work.

Comment: Did you try just Posting a new message explaining the problem? It may not be the "official" method but the forum is monitored by Microsoft engineers. Maybe even also post about your inability to report an issue, since it might be an international problem.

Comment: "just Posting a new message explaining the problem" >How to do so?